# Dropdown Menu Is Weird

Tags: php, html

Any PHP Experts: I'm a beginner. I have this Reference Electrode Converter:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Referance Electrode Converter</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Referance Electrode Converter</h1>
        <h6>After Pressing Convert The Dropdown Goes Back to It's Defaults</h6>
        <form action="index.php" method="get">
            <input type="text" name="input" placeholder="Enter Amount"></input>
            <select name="dropdown">
                <option value="SHE" selected><sub>SHE</sub></option>
                <option value="SCE"><sub>SCE</sub></option>
                <option value="AG"><sub>Ag/AgCl</sub></option>
                <option value="MSE">MSE</option>
                <option value="CSE">CSE</option>
            </select>
            <br />
            <?php

$cc_input = $_GET['input'];
$cc_dropdown = $_GET['dropdown'];
$cc_odropdown = $_GET['odropdown'];

if(isset($_GET['sbmt']))
{
    if($cc_dropdown == 'SHE') {
        if($cc_odropdown == 'SHE') {
            $output = $cc_input * 1 . "V";
            echo "<input type='text' value='$output' disabled/>";
        } elseif($cc_odropdown == 'SCE') {
            $output = $cc_input + 0.2415 . "V";
            echo "<input type='text' value='$output' disabled/>";
        } elseif($cc_odropdown == 'AG') {
            $output = $cc_input + 0.222 . "V";
            echo "<input type='text' value='$output' disabled/>";
        } elseif($cc_odropdown == 'MSE') {
            $output = $cc_input - 0.615 . "V";
            echo "<input type='text' value='$output' disabled/>";
        } elseif($cc_odropdown == 'CSE') {
            $output = $cc_input - 0.318 . "V";
            echo "<input type='text' value='$output' disabled/>";
        }
    }
    elseif($cc_dropdown == 'SCE') {
        if($cc_odropdown == 'SHE') {
            $output = $cc_input - 0.2415 . "V";
            echo "<input type='text' value='$output' disabled/>";
        } elseif($cc_odropdown == 'SCE') {
            $output = $cc_input * 1 . "V";
            echo "<input type='text' value='$output' disabled/>";
        } elseif($cc_odropdown == 'AG') {
            $output = $cc_input + 0.0195 . "V";
            echo "<input type='text' value='$output' disabled/>";
        } elseif($cc_odropdown == 'MSE') {
            $output = $cc_input - 0.3735 . "V";
            echo "<input type='text' value='$output' disabled/>";
        } elseif($cc_odropdown == 'CSE') {
            $output = $cc_input - 0.765 . "V";
            echo "<input type='text' value='$output' disabled/>";
        }

    }
    elseif($cc_dropdown == 'AG') {
        if($cc_odropdown == 'SHE') {
            $output = $cc_input - 0.222 . "V";
            echo "<input type='text' value='$output' disabled/>";
        } elseif($cc_odropdown == 'SCE') {
            $output = $cc_input - 0.0195;
            echo "<input type='text' value='$output' disabled/>";
        } elseif($cc_odropdown == 'AG') {
            $output = $cc_input * 1 . "V";
            echo "<input type='text' value='$output' disabled/>";
        } elseif($cc_odropdown == 'MSE') {
            $output = $cc_input - 0.393 . "V";
            echo "<input type='text' value='$output' disabled/>";
        } elseif($cc_odropdown == 'CSE') {
            $output = $cc_input - 0.096 . "V";
            echo "<input type='text' value='$output' disabled/>";
        }
    }
    elseif($cc_dropdown == 'MSE') {
        if($cc_odropdown == 'SHE') {
            $output = $cc_input + 0.615 . "V";
            echo "<input type='text' value='$output' disabled/>";
        } elseif($cc_odropdown == 'SCE') {
            $output = $cc_input + 0.3735 . "V";
            echo "<input type='text' value='$output' disabled/>";
        } elseif($cc_odropdown == 'AG') {
            $output = $cc_input + 0.393 . "V";
            echo "<input type='text' value='$output' disabled/>";
        } elseif($cc_odropdown == 'MSE') {
            $output = $cc_input * 1 . "V";
            echo "<input type='text' value='$output' disabled/>";
        } elseif($cc_odropdown == 'CSE') {
            $output = $cc_input + 0.297 . "V";
            echo "<input type='text' value='$output' disabled/>";
        }
    }
    elseif($cc_dropdown == 'CSE') {
        if($cc_odropdown == 'SHE') {
            $output = $cc_input + 0.318 . "V";
            echo "<input type='text' value='$output' disabled/>";
        } elseif($cc_odropdown == 'SCE') {
            $output = $cc_input + 0.0765 . "V";
            echo "<input type='text' value='$output' disabled/>";
        } elseif($cc_odropdown == 'AG') {
            $output = $cc_input + 0.096 . "V";
            echo "<input type='text' value='$output' disabled/>";
        } elseif($cc_odropdown == 'MSE') {
            $output = $cc_input - 0.297 . "V";
            echo "<input type='text' value='$output' disabled/>";
        } elseif($cc_odropdown == 'CSE') {
            $output = $cc_input * 1 . "V";
            echo "<input type='text' value='$output' disabled/>";
        }
    }
}
            ?>
            <select name="odropdown">
                <option value="SHE"><sub>SHE</sub></option>
                <option value="SCE" selected><sub>SCE</sub></option>
                <option value="AG"><sub>Ag/AgCl</sub></option>
                <option value="MSE">MSE</option>
                <option value="CSE">CSE</option>
            </select>
            <br />
            <input type="submit" name="sbmt" value="Convert!"></input>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

The weird thing is that when I click "Convert," the dropdown menus go back to whatever the HTML "selected" variable was. What can I do to fix this issue?

Thanks
-Lorelo

Comment: You Dont Need To Understand What Referanse Electrode is, Think of it Like Currency

Comment: You misspelled "reference" in a second way now, just saying...

Comment: Oh Thanks...... I Feel Bad now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I'm not sure if this is only a problem on my server, but it threw errors when I tried to get undefined GET request variables, so I did this:

```
if(isset($_GET['input'])) $cc_input = $_GET['input'];
if(isset($_GET['dropdown'])) $cc_dropdown = $_GET['dropdown'];
if(isset($_GET['odropdown'])) $cc_odropdown = $_GET['odropdown'];
```

Anyway, in order to fix your original problem, you should check what the values of $cc_dropdown and $cc_odropdown are. Depending on that, you should decide where to echo the "selected" attribute.

**UPDATE**

Here's what I did:

```
...
    <body>
    <?php

if(isset($_GET['input'])) $cc_input = $_GET['input'];
if(isset($_GET['dropdown'])) $cc_dropdown = $_GET['dropdown'];
if(isset($_GET['odropdown'])) $cc_odropdown = $_GET['odropdown'];

    ?>
        <h1>Referance Electrode Converter</h1>
        <h6>After Pressing Convert The Dropdown Goes Back to It's Defaults</h6>
        <form action="index.php" method="get">
            <input type="text" name="input" placeholder="Enter Amount"></input>
            <select name="dropdown">
            <?php if(!isset($_GET['sbmt'])): ?>
                <option value="SHE" selected><sub>SHE</sub></option>
                <option value="SCE"><sub>SCE</sub></option>
                <option value="AG"><sub>Ag/AgCl</sub></option>
                <option value="MSE">MSE</option>
                <option value="CSE">CSE</option>
            <?php else: ?>
                <option value="SHE" <?php if($cc_dropdown=="SHE") echo "selected";  ?> ><sub>SHE</sub></option>
                <option value="SCE" <?php if($cc_dropdown=="SCE") echo "selected";  ?> ><sub>SCE</sub></option>
                <option value="AG" <?php if($cc_dropdown=="AG") echo "selected";  ?> ><sub>Ag/AgCl</sub></option>
                <option value="MSE" <?php if($cc_dropdown=="MSE") echo "selected";  ?> >MSE</option>
                <option value="CSE" <?php if($cc_dropdown=="CSE") echo "selected";  ?> >CSE</option>
            <?php endif; ?>
            </select>
            <br />
            <?php

if(isset($_GET['sbmt']))
{
        ...
```

**UPDATE 2**

I forgot to mention that you must also do this for the other dropdown list. This is only for the upper one. Don't worry, though - it's analogous.

Comment: Do You Use PHP 7 or 5?

Comment: Do I Copy Paste This?

Comment: @Lorelo 5. I use PHP 5.6.16. I guess it really does depend on the version then. Either way, those errors weren't a big deal.

Comment: I think the conditional may be backwards, this first should be if(!isset($_GET['sbmt'])):

Comment: Dude Thank You Very Much!

Comment: @heybignick Yeah, I fixed that right before I saw your comment. Thanks though!

Comment: @Lorelo No problem! And don't only copy-paste, because you have to change a few things for the other drop-down list. As long as you're understood my idea, you should be able to do it even yourself.

Comment: Just Accepted Your Answer. And It Works

Comment: Saddly i Cannot Upvode ;(